Pointing many apps to the same Firebase app
I am going to be "white-labelling" many instances of the same app which has Firebase services such as Analytics, Crashlytics, Performance Monitoring, Cloud Messaging.
Each of the many apps will have a different package/bundle ID (separate app store listings).
But I want them all to point to the same "Firebase App". I want them to appear to Firebase as essentially the same app: point to the same Analytics, Crashlytics etc. I don't want to have separate Firebase app configurations.
I would bundle the same google-services.json etc into every app except that build fails because of the mismatching package/bundle IDs...
Is it possible in any way to have multiple package/bundle IDs point to the same Firebase app configuration?

The recommended practices for this are covered in the documentation.

Multi-tenancy can lead to serious configuration and data privacy concerns, including unintended issues with analytics aggregation, shared authentication, overly-complex database structures, and difficulties with security rules.
Generally, if a set of apps don't share the same data and configurations, strongly consider registering each app with a different Firebase project.
For example, if you develop a white-label application, each independently labeled app should have its own Firebase project, and the iOS and Android versions of that label should be in the same Firebase project. Each independently labeled app shouldn't (for privacy reasons) share data with the others.

What you're suggesting in your post is the exact opposite of what Firebase strongly recommends.
I understand the reason why you might want the opposite, but you are inheriting a different set of (potentially bigger) problems by putting all the apps in the same project.

Thank you. Yeah in my case however all apps do share the same data and configuration and are otherwise identical aside from package ID and branding.

The same page of documentation prescribes what to do under the heading "Registering app variants with Firebase projects ... If you have multiple build variants that could share the same Firebase resources". You will necessarily end up with different configurations for each of your apps even thought they all use the same project.  This is unavoidable - you will have to figure out how to build your variants with the correct configuration.

Yeah I'd have to automate the process of registering and embedding app configurations. It's a shame that I'll then have to monitor many separate apps in Crashlytics, Perf etc too. If only... ‍♂️
